# Is HTML5 Session Storage secure?

Tags: html, session, mobile, cookies, cross-browser

Is *HTML5 Session Storage* secure? What I mean by this is:

1. Can the contents be edited?
2. Can the contents be viewed?
3. Can the contents be deleted?
4. Does session storage work with all major browsers?
5. Is session storage mobile-compatible with these same browsers?

I'm looking at migrating away from cookie-based sessions to HTML5 sessions and could do with an understanding of Session storage from the security viewpoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is editable, view-able and delete-able by user.

To do so,
Say if you are using chrome, open "Developer Tools" > "Resources" > "Session Storage"

User has full access... So NOT SECURE.